# how to allow -non_number as arguments in python argparse

Tags: python, argparse

```
python test.py --arg -foo -bar
test.py: error: argument --arg: expected at least one argument

python test.py --arg -8
['-8']
```

How do I allow -non_number to work with argparse?

Is there a way to disable short arguments?

Comment: This is the problem of handling an argument that looks like a flag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48322986/python-argparse-passing-argument-to-argument; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174992/cant-get-argparse-to-read-quoted-string-with-dashes-in-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call it like this:

```
python test.py --arg='-foo'
```

To allow specifying multiple:

```
parser.add_argument('--arg', action='append')
# call like python test.py --arg=-foo --arg=-bar
```

Comment: doesn't work for more than 1 arguments though. Edited question to reflect

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `nargs` parameter to argparser.

```
parser.add_argument('--arg', nargs='?')
```

At the moment, `--arg` is interpreting the value `'-8'` as the input, whereas it thinks `'-f'` (with parameters `'oo'`) is a new argument.

Alternatively, you could use `action='store_true'`, which will represent the presence or absence of the argument with a boolean.

```
parser.add_argument('--arg', action='store_true')
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs